# Start MonitorSwitcher.exe via SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, multiple-monitors

I use [Monitor Profile Switcher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/monitorswitcher/) to painlessly switch to the graphics card output for my projector by clicking a .lnk.

Now I want to automate this even further, and execute Monitor Profile Switcher with SSH. But to my great dismay, even the command line version only works when Windows "thinks" it's being executed on a real session (i.e. with a monitor) and not a virtual one.

It works:

- when I open up cmd.exe locally and do `MonitorSwitcher.exe -load:Projector.xml`,
- when I do it on the same session via TightVNC

but it would NOT work when

- executed via an SSH cmd session
- or in a cmd.exe window on a Remote Desktop session.

Simply nothing happens.

I'm looking for either a workaround to that particular problem, or another solution to switch my display settings remotely so I can control it from my raspberry pi and openhab.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of researching and trying out stuff, I found a way to make MonitorSwitcher work via SSH.

You'll need PsExec, which is available from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

```
PsExec64.exe -u Username -p Password -i 1 C:\Path\To\MonitorSwitcher.exe -load:C:\Path\To\Layoutconfig.xml
```

Note that this only works when the user is logged in on the "physical" console, i.e. no lock screen is active. If you want to unlock the screen from ssh first, you need to execute

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "$sessionid=((quser $env:USERNAME | select -Skip 1) -split '\s+')[2]; tscon $sessionid /dest:console" 2> UnlockErrors.log
```